# error: 'annotate' attribute directive ignored

Tags: android, android-ndk

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjYEM.png)

I am trying to build a project using Android NDK r16b. But, it is giving an error

**'annotate' attribute directive ignored {-Werror=attributes}**.

I am using

**-isystem android-ndk-r16b/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi/**

and

**--sysroot=android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/**

Can anyone help in resolving this? It was working fine when I was working on NDK-r14b.

Answer (score 0):

Your build commands are incorrect. Don't set up your system include/library paths manually; use a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain).